# What is the number of possibilities to interpret a litteral number string?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Me and some friends came up with the following problem :

Given a string of numbers of length $n$, what is the number of possibilities to interpret this string as digits (while not accounting for pelling problems) ? 
For example with "one three two one", $n = 4$, we could interpret it as "$1321$", or even "$311$" (one three and two ones).
To simplify a bit, some additionnal rules are that two consecutive numbers cannot be the same, and that a digit can only demultiply the one after him, for example "two three one" cannot be interpreted as "$3131$" (two times three one).
This might be related to the look and say sequence, we just don't now in what way.

Our conjecture is that this number is fibonacci($n$) (with fibonacci($0$) = fibonacci($1$) = $1$). This works up to n = 30, but we did not manage to complete a proof $\forall$$n\in$$\mathbb{N}$. Our idea was to represent the string of length n by a sequence $A_1 A_2 A_3...A_n$, with $A_i\in \{\{1, 1*\}, \{2, 2*\},\dots\}$ $\forall$$i\gt 1$, and $A_1\in \{\{1\}, \{2\},\dots\}$. A number "star" would represent a number that got itself demultiplied by the previous one.

This representation is probably really bad (and maybe doesn't even work), but at least we can represent all the sequences of length $n$ as the set $A_1\times A_2\times \dots \times A_n$ minus the possibilities where two number "stars" are consecutive.

After a bit of research on the internet, we didn't manage to find anything related to this, and so here we are. What are your thoughts on this, is our conjecture reasonable ? if yes, how could we prove it ? (We tried by induction, without success...)

I also want to apologize if this post is not well-written, doesn't follow the math.stackexchange rules, or if the problem is not well formulated. As second year computer science students, this is totally new to us.

Thank you !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "demultiplied"?

Comment: So, "one three two one" can be interpreted as $1321$, or $1311$, or $12221$, or $321$, or $311$, is that right? So it's the number of way of parking cars and trucks in $n$ parking spaces, if each car takes one space, and each truck takes two? Should be easy to write down a simple linear recurrence for this, and then to solve it by the standard techniques. (With $n=4$, you have cccc, and tcc, and ctc, and cct, and tt, where each c is a car and each t is a truck.)

Comment: I'm so sorry, read your response but totally forgot to answer (was in exam period)... Your answer makes total sense, thank you very much !

Comment: If you now see how to answer the question, Mat, let me encourage you to write up what you now know and post it as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tried to post the sketch of a proof. Just a question, I did not do it yet, but am I allowed to tag you / mention you in the actual answer (to thank you for your help) or is it against the rules ?

Comment: I think it's common courtesy to acknowledge getting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cars and trucks analogy

We can see this string as a succession of cars (c), representing one number, and trucks (t), representing two consecutive numbers. For example "one two" can be either cc which would represent the interpretation "$12$" or t for "$2$".

Our conjecture P($n$) : "the number of possibilities for a string of length $n$ is fibonacci($n$)" can be proven by showing that there are fibonacci($n$) ways to assemble c's and t's, knowing that c's take one place, t's take two places, and we have a total of n places. We can prove that this is true by induction : the base case would consist of proving that P($1$) and P($2$) are true. Then, we can show that P($n$), P($n+1$) implies P($n+2$) by noticing that the two only ways to build the string of length $n+2$ are either adding a truck to the string of length $n$, or adding a car to the string of length $n+1$, which can be done in fibonacci($n$) $+$ fibonacci($n+1$) $=$ fibonacci($n+2$) ways by the inductive hypothesis.

Hence the conjecture that there are fibonacci($n$) ways to interpret a length-$n$ litteral string of this type is true.

Thank you, @GerryMyerson for your help !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).